# Java посмотреть что творится в рантайме

Tags: java, jvm

Как можно посмотреть что сейчас находится в куче, какие стеки созданы и другую информацию по приложению? И можно ли? 
Например как узнать сколько объектов создалось физически в данном примере?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hello";
    String s1 = "Hel" + "lo";
    String s2 = new String(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно посмотреть общую информацию при помощи [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/).

Много возможностей предоставляет технология [Java Management Extensions](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions). С помощью нее вы не только сможете узнать состояние вашей системы, но и изменить параметры системы - осуществить настройку (без перезапуска)

Что бы узнать информацию о вашем коде вы можете использовать профилировщик (profiler). На рынке есть несколько различных профилеровщиков - [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/), [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), [XRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/xrebel/), [NetBeans Profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/) и пр.